# How to fix ActionNoPermission

Tags: python, rpc, nearprotocol

I'm trying to use the near-api-py library to lock the currency on allnodes.com

```
def sign_and_send_tx():
    _signer = Signer(my_wallet_id, key_pair)
    _account = Account(account_id=my_wallet_id, provider=near_provider, signer=_signer)
    amount_to_stake = 1 * NEAR
    tx = _account.stake(public_key=_signer.public_key, amount=amount_to_stake,
                        receiver_id=allnodes_validator_id)
    return tx
```

, but I get the error:

```
near_api.account.TransactionError: {'ActionError': {'index': 0, 'kind':
{'ActorNoPermission': {'account_id': 'all nodes.pool v1.near',
'actor_id': 'efe6e8a8f9bc098a672dcfe252a42666dfea38562cf627e5ff8a938c7b.near'}}}}
```

why does it occur? how to fix it and implement staking. thanks

I looked through the documentation on docs.near.org . however, I did not find the solution I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActorNoPermission` error means that the account trying to perform the operation doesn't have permission to do so. In this case, the operation is staking, and the account trying to perform this operation is `efe6e8a8f9bc098a672dcfe252a42666dfea38562cf627e5ff8a938c7b.near`.

When it comes to staking in NEAR, it is important to remember that only the owner of an account can stake NEAR tokens from that account. The `actor_id` in your error message indicates that the account `efe6e8a8f9bc098a672dcfe252a42666dfea38562cf627e5ff8a938c7b.near` is trying to stake tokens from the `allnodes.poolv1.near` account.

The `allnodes.poolv1.near` is [a staking pool contract](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/staking-pool), you usually need to call the specific methods provided by that contract to deposit and stake your tokens. In NEAR, you typically don't stake to a validator directly from your account, you interact with the staking pool contract methods.

You might want to replace the `stake` method call with a `function_call` method call to interact with the staking pool contract. You would need to call the appropriate function on the staking pool contract that represents depositing and staking tokens.

Here is a pseudocode example:

```py
_account.function_call(
    contract_id='allnodes.poolv1.near',
    method_name='deposit_and_stake',
    args={},
    gas=300000000000000,
    amount=amount_to_stake,
)
```

Comment: @АлесяСелезнева Please, create separate questions as they are off-topic and also hard to answer in the comments